# Automapper - Mapping Entity to Enum

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an entity to a enum. As I was searching for a source I found this:

```
using Should;

public enum OrderStatus : short
{
    InProgress = 0,
Complete = 1
}

public enum OrderStatusDto
{
    InProgress = 0,
Complete = 1
}

[Test]
public void Example()
{
    Mapper.Map<OrderStatus, OrderStatusDto>(OrderStatus.InProgress)
                .ShouldEqual(OrderStatusDto.InProgress);
    Mapper.Map<OrderStatus, short>(OrderStatus.Complete).ShouldEqual((short)1);
    Mapper.Map<OrderStatus, string>(OrderStatus.Complete).ShouldEqual("Complete");
    Mapper.Map<short, OrderStatus>(1).ShouldEqual(OrderStatus.Complete);
    Mapper.Map<string, OrderStatus>("Complete").ShouldEqual(OrderStatus.Complete);
}
```

but I think this works for only enum-to-enum mapping. because when I try to use `.ShouldEqual`, intellisense can't find it. In that codeblock, there is a reference that's called *Should* but I couldn't find its reference anywhere.

Any ideas about how to use automapper to map between enum and entity/class? 
Any ideas about using Should?

@I updated the question because without seeing the actual code, it's harder to consider a solution. Here is the code snippet that might be needed:

```
public class ParameterEnum
{
/// <summary>
/// Enum Sayisi: 2650, Son Guncelleme Tarihi: 21.2.2013 09:40:37
/// </summary>
public enum Parameters : int 
{
...
IsEmriTuruIsTalebi = 138, 
<summary>
Adi: Kalite Öneri; ID: 2218; Seviyesi: 3; Aciklamasi: ; Aktif Mi: True
</summary>
...}}
```

and this is where normal mapping done:

```
                    isEmriEntity.IsEmriTuruId = (int)ParameterEnum.Parameters.IsEmriTuruIsTalebi;
```

Comment: `ShouldEqual` is part of the test that demonstrates this feature. It is not part of AutoMapper and you don't need it.

Comment: then **.ForMember** method should work for this one as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into ITypeConverter. Something like this should do the job:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderStatus, OrderStatusDto>().ConvertUsing(new OrderStatusConverter());
```

and your converter would look like so:

```
public class OrderStatusConverter: ITypeConverter<OrderStatus, OrderStatusDto>
{
    public OrderStatusDto Convert(OrderStatus source)
    {
        return (OrderStatusDto)source;
    }
}
```

That should be enough to apply the same approach to any other cross-type mappings in your DTOs.

EDIT:

On your enum conversion error, using this as an example for clarity (an enum is not a DTO):

```
    public enum ExampleEnum : short
    {
        SomeValue,
        SomeOtherValue,
        BigValue = 100,
    }

    public enum AnotherEnum
    {
        Foo,
        Bar,
    }
```

This should make the enum conversion clearer (don't cast to int at all).

```
    private void Test()
    {
        // Casting to int only works when the value is 0

        // This works (SomeValue = 0)
        AnotherEnum example = (int) ExampleEnum.SomeValue;

        // This won't even compile (SomeOtherValue = 1)
        AnotherEnum example2 = (int) ExampleEnum.SomeOtherValue;

        // Casting to another enum works fine
        AnotherEnum example2 = (AnotherEnum) ExampleEnum.SomeOtherValue;

        // Just be careful of values that don't exist in the target enum
        // This will compile even though it won't work at run-time (BigValue = 100)
        AnotherEnum example2 = (AnotherEnum) ExampleEnum.BigValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The int cast was wrong. I have VisualStudio handy now so was able to check instead of just 'coding' in the browser. Hope the answer's clearer now.